# Combine Code First and Database First Approaches

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

Let say I have an existing project that its entity classes are created by using **Database First Approach** from server A. Subsequently I create a new database with the exact same name in server B and hence import the data from server A. Next, by using **Code First Approach**, I further add in two tables (to be specific), and update the database in server B. Finally, I have deleted the existing edmx model in the existing project, and further add it again by using **ADO Entity Framework methodology** from server B. Notice that I am currently unable to reference the variable type from the auto generated model class that I have created earlier, in fact they are all in same name. May I know how am I suppose to go about this? Or I shouldn't be doing this? Well I just wanna try something new. Hope to get some explanation.

Comment: First sentence makes no sense. There's no way to create database using DB-first approach. In this case, you create DB on your own and let EF create entity classes...

Comment: I understand code first can be created in c# code without doing in Database.  @MichalTurczyn

Comment: Hi @MichałTurczyn thanks for the alert. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would do:

First of all, store two connection strings in your app, one for server A, one for server B. In context class constructor you can specify which connection string to use (let's say conn. string A is for A db and conn. string B for B db). Something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connStrA" ... />
  <add name="connStrB" ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

First one is created, because you used DB first approach. Then, you have to switch auto-generated context class. You have to change parameter passed to the constructor, on default it should be something like: `public MyContextClass() : base("name=connStrA"){}`.
You have to change it to use `connStrB`.

Do your changes (using migrations), and they will be reflected in DB, that you have pointed in connection string that you specified in mentioned constructor.